# python3でframe内のデータを取得する

Tags: html, python

Pythonでhtmlのframe内のデータを取得するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
私が取得したいWebページには<noframes>があるのでframeの内容を取得せずにそちらの内容を取得してしまいます。こちらが<frame>に対応しているとサーバーに思わせるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: noframesの判断をしているのはサーバーではなくブラウザです。サーバーはframeの中身まで一緒に返してくれるわけではないので、ＵＲＬをＨＴＭＬから抽出して手動で取得してください。

Comment: 手動取得について、今更かもしれないですが、`Beautiful Soup`と`Requests`を組み合わせれば比較的楽に実現できると思います。